# Is an iPhone SDK patch available, or do I need to download the entire tool set?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've looked around Apple's site, and searched Google, but I can't find anything. I was wanting to patch the iPhone SDK to version 3.1.2 so I can deploy to my device again. I see the download for the iPhone SDK/Xcode bundle, but I was wondering if there was a patch that wasn't 2.7gb.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've ever been aware, every update to the SDK required a full redeployment of the 2.7GB XCode stack. Of course, "as far as I've ever been aware" dates back to just the 3.0 beta, as I'm a relatively new dev for the platform. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a patch, I believe that you always download the entire .dmg